# Permanently mute a particular GUI application

Tags: linux-mint, audio, cinnamon, reboot, notifications

I have installed [slgobinath/SafeEyes: Protect your eyes from eye strain using this simple and beautiful, yet extensible break reminder](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes). It doesn't have any ways to mute or control the volume sound yet.

Is it possible that one can permanently mute this software (it auto restarts after reboot)?